Best way to handle mask and image
I'm working on a crop view... I have a problem..
the first three photos that I show you represent the cropView in its initial state (so not like this using the offset to move the photo)
  
as you can see if we take the girl's shoe as a reference point we notice that it is always outside the area of ​​the circular mask even if I use split view for 2/3, 1/2, 1/3 the image fits perfectly
If, however, we look at these other 3 photos in which I used the drag gesture, always taking the reference point, i.e. the girl's shoe, we notice that with each change of the split view it does not always remain in the same position. This certainly changes due to the image measurements but I just can't find a way to understand why it happens.
  
If I don't use the drag gesture the mask and the photo are perfect in all three first photos but as soon as the offset value changes with the dragGesture I get this difference in the last three photos
Can you help me understand? I hope I was able to explain myself correctly
public struct CropView: PlatformView {
   
    var selectedPhoto: UIImage
    let prefersShape: Mask
    
    public init(selectedPhoto: UIImage, prefersShape: Mask = .circle) {
        self.selectedPhoto = selectedPhoto
        self.prefersShape = prefersShape
    }
    
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass
    
    @State private var viewSize: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = .zero
    
    private var maskScale: CGFloat {
        isCompact ? 0.6 : 0.65
    }
    
    @State private var photoSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                let currentOffset = lastOffset + value.translation
                offset = currentOffset
               // updateOffsetLimits(currentOffset: currentOffset)
            }
            .onEnded { _ in lastOffset = offset }
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
                        
        ZStack {
            Image(uiImage: selectedPhoto)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio( contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(photoSize)
                .offset(offset)
                .mask {
                    Rectangle().opacity(0.5)
                        .overlay {
                            prefersShape.shape
                                .blendMode(.destinationOver)
                        }
                }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .gesture(dragGesture)
        .onGeometryChange(for: CGSize.self) { proxy in
            proxy.size
        } action: { newValue in
            viewSize = newValue
            
            let isLandscape = newValue.width > newValue.height
            let reference = isLandscape ? newValue.height : newValue
                .width
            photoSize = prefersShape.size(relativeTo: .init(width: reference, height: reference)).scaledBy(maskScale)

        }
    }
}


extension View {
    func frame(_ size: CGSize) -> some View {
        frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
}


@MainActor
protocol PlatformView: View {
    var horizontalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass? { get }
    var verticalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass? { get }
    var isCompact: Bool { get }
    var isRegular: Bool { get }
}

extension PlatformView {
    var isCompact: Bool { horizontalSizeClass == .compact || verticalSizeClass == .compact }
    var isRegular: Bool { horizontalSizeClass == .regular && verticalSizeClass == .regular }
}

Update for Mask enum and Extensions
public enum Mask {
    case circle, square, 
    
    var shape: AnyShape {
        switch self {
        case .circle: return AnyShape(.circle)
        case .square, .rectangle : return AnyShape(.rect)
        }
    }

  func size(relativeTo size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let isLandscape = size.width > size.height
    let reference = isLandscape ? size.height : size
        .width

    switch self {
    case .circle, .square :
        return .init(width: size.width, height: size.width)
    }
}

extension CGSize {
    static func + (lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        .init(width: lhs.width + rhs.width, height: lhs.height + rhs.height)
    }
    
    func scaledBy(_ scale: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        .init(width: self.width * scale, height: self.height * scale)
    }
}

Original Image of example


Please show a [mre]. You should be able to show some code that can be directly copy and pasted into a new project and reproduce the issue.

@Sweeper The code I used is everything I posted in my question except a simple enum where I assign the shape of the mask returning a Circle() for circle and a Rectangle() for square

Yes I can see that. Show that enum, or remove it from the code. It would be great if you also included the original image of the girl.

@Sweeper Thanks for your patience.. I hope things get better this way

Okay, clearly you have not actually copy and pasted this into a new project and check. I can guess what most of the undefined things do, except size(relativeTo:). Other things you didn't show includes the + operator on CGSizes, and the scaledBy method on (presumably) CGSize.

@Sweeper no I have not made a new project because this is already new I only have that struct I also confirm that + is an extension of cgsize and sizeTo is a method that defines height=size.width and width=size.width for portrait and the opposite for the landscape for the size of the circle and the square sorry I went out to pick up my son from school and I'm answering you from my cell phone

@Sweeper I update my question with extension

The explanation for why the image is shifted by different amounts when the view size changes is because the drag offset is being stored as an absolute size (= absolute number of points). This size relates to the size of the image at the time that drag was performed. When the image is shown on a smaller screen, the same offset will cause a larger movement of the image and vice versa.
To fix, the drag offset needs to be normalized. Then, when the offset is applied to the image, the normalized offset needs to be scaled in accordance with the current image size.
The following changes can be made to CropView to get it to work this way:

Add a reference size for normalization

let refSizeForOffset: CGFloat = 1000


In the .onChanged closure, compute and save the normalized offset

.onChanged { value in
    let normalizedOffset = CGSize(
        width: value.translation.width * refSizeForOffset / photoSize.width,
        height: value.translation.height * refSizeForOffset / photoSize.height
    )
    let currentOffset = lastOffset + normalizedOffset
    offset = currentOffset
}


Add a computed property for computing the scaled offset

private var scaledOffset: CGSize {
    CGSize(
        width: offset.width * photoSize.width / refSizeForOffset,
        height: offset.height * photoSize.height / refSizeForOffset
    )
}


Apply the scaled offset to the image

Image(uiImage: selectedPhoto)
    // ... other modifiers as before
    .offset(scaledOffset) //  scaledOffset replaces offset from before
    .mask {
        // ...
    }


Thank you very much, your solution seems to work very well... I wanted to ask you a question about the refSizeForOffset value of 1000, why not set it to .zero or 1.0?

@kAiN 0.0 will not work, 1.0 would work. I chose 1000 because the values are easier to relate to when viewed as debug output. Ps. Thanks for the upvote!

Furthermore, will all this cause any problems when I have to set limits for the offset so as not to go out of the mask?

@kAiN You can choose whether to apply limits before or after normalization, both ways should work (because it's effectively the same limit).

the positive vote is really the minimum for the help you gave me.. thank you so much..I will definitely take advantage of your patience for other questions... I have always had a bad relationship with gestures :D in fact I will definitely have problems with the mask limits and their calculation. I accept your answer

hi benzy, sorry, I wanted to avoid asking another question since it always concerns the topic of your answer.. can I show you in chat a problem regarding the management of offset limits?

I preferred to ask a new question including all the code to avoid misunderstandings
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79284656/calculate-offset-limit-of-mask-bounds
