Calculate Offset Limit of mask bounds
Hi all I'm trying to set the offset limits so that the image during the dragGesture never exceeds the outlines of the mask...
Thanks to the help of Benzy Neez I obtain a scaleOffset value that I use for the image so that the original offset takes into account the variations in size of the image but at this point I can no longer make the limits work..
I'm definitely doing something very stupid wrong but I can't find the error
I'll show you the code
@MainActor
protocol PlatformView: View {
    var horizontalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass? { get }
    var verticalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass? { get }
    var isCompact: Bool { get }
    var isRegular: Bool { get }
}

extension PlatformView {
    var isCompact: Bool { horizontalSizeClass == .compact || verticalSizeClass == .compact }
    var isRegular: Bool { horizontalSizeClass == .regular && verticalSizeClass == .regular }
}

public enum Mask {
    case circle, square, rectangle(aspectRatio: AspectRatio)
    
    var shape: AnyShape {
        switch self {
        case .circle: return AnyShape(.circle)
        case .square, .rectangle : return AnyShape(.rect)
        }
    }
    
    func size(relativeTo size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let isLandscape = size.width > size.height
        let reference = isLandscape ? size.height : size
            .width

        switch self {
        case .circle, .square :
            return .init(width: reference, height: reference)
        
        case .rectangle(let aspectRatio):
            return .init(width: reference, height: reference * aspectRatio.ratio)
        }
    }

    public enum AspectRatio {
        case ar4_3, ar16_9
        var ratio: CGFloat {
            switch self {
            case .ar4_3: return 4/3
            case .ar16_9: return 16/9
            }
        }
    }
}

@Observable public class CroxioManagaer {
     
    var offset: CGSize = .zero
    var lastOffset: CGSize = .zero
    var photoSize: CGSize = .zero
    var maskSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    func currentOffset(translation: CGSize) -> CGSize  {
        let currentOffset: CGSize = .init(width: translation.width / photoSize.width, height: translation.height / photoSize.height)
        return lastOffset + currentOffset
       
    }
    
    func limitedOffset(translation: CGSize) {
        let ratioX = photoSize.width / maskSize.width
        let ratioY = photoSize.height / maskSize.height
        let maxX = ((maskSize.width - photoSize.width) / 2) / ratioX
        let maxY = ((maskSize.height - photoSize.height) / 2) / ratioY
        let currentOffset = currentOffset(translation: translation)
        let width = max(-maxX, min(maxX, currentOffset.width))
        let height = max(-maxY, min(maxY, currentOffset.height))
        offset = .init(width: width, height: height)
    }
    
    func saveOffset() {
        lastOffset = offset
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    private func aspectRatio(_ size: CGSize = .zero) -> CGFloat {
        return size == .zero ? self.size.width / self.size.height : size.width / size.height
    }
        
    func adaptPhotoSize(to size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let photoAspectRatio = aspectRatio()
        let maskAspectRatio = aspectRatio(size)
        
        if photoAspectRatio > maskAspectRatio {
            // La foto è più larga rispetto alla maschera: scala per altezza
            let width = size.height * photoAspectRatio
            return .init(width: width, height: size.height)
        } else {
            // La foto è più alta rispetto alla maschera: scala per larghezza
            let height = size.width * photoAspectRatio
            return .init(width: size.width, height: height)
        }
    }
}

extension CGSize {
    static func + (lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        .init(width: lhs.width + rhs.width, height: lhs.height + rhs.height)
    }
}

public struct Croxio: PlatformView {
    var selectedPhoto: UIImage
    let prefersShape: Mask
    
    public init(selectedPhoto: UIImage, prefersShape: Mask = .circle) {
        self.selectedPhoto = selectedPhoto
        self.prefersShape = prefersShape
    }
    
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass
    
    @State private var manager = CroxioManagaer()
    
    private var scaledOffset: CGSize {
        CGSize(
            width: manager.offset.width * manager.photoSize.width,
            height: manager.offset.height * manager.photoSize.height
        )
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(uiImage: selectedPhoto)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(manager.photoSize)
                .offset(scaledOffset)

            Color.primary.opacity(0.5)
                .mask {
                    Rectangle()
                        .overlay {
                            prefersShape.shape
                                .frame(manager.maskSize)
                                .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                        }
                }
        }
        .onGeometryChange(for: CGSize.self, of: { proxy in
            proxy.size
        }, action: { newValue in
            manager.maskSize = prefersShape.size(relativeTo: newValue * 0.7)
            manager.photoSize = selectedPhoto.adaptPhotoSize(to: manager.maskSize)
        })
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged({ value in
                    manager.limitedOffset(translation: value.translation)
                })
                .onEnded({ _ in manager.saveOffset() })
        )
    }
}


I think there are 3 problems.

In the function adaptPhotoSize, the second calculation should be using division instead of multiplying:

if photoAspectRatio > maskAspectRatio {
    // La foto è più larga rispetto alla maschera: scala per altezza
    let width = size.height * photoAspectRatio
    return .init(width: width, height: size.height)
} else {
    // La foto è più alta rispetto alla maschera: scala per larghezza
    let height = size.width / photoAspectRatio //  here
    return .init(width: size.width, height: height)
}


The function limitedOffset was not working correctly. Try it like this:

func limitedOffset(translation: CGSize) {
    let maxX = (photoSize.width - maskSize.width) / (2 * photoSize.width)
    let maxY = (photoSize.height - maskSize.height) / (2 * photoSize.height)
    let currentOffset = currentOffset(translation: translation)
    let width = max(-maxX, min(maxX, currentOffset.width))
    let height = max(-maxY, min(maxY, currentOffset.height))
    offset = .init(width: width, height: height)
}


Photo scaling may impact the ZStack size

The reason why you didn't notice that the photo had the wrong size before is because you were scaling it to fill the display area. You shouldn't need to use either .scaledToFill or scaledToFit, because you are setting a frame on the photo with an exact size.
However, there is another issue.
The photo is contained inside the ZStack. If the photo exceeds the bounds of the display then it causes the ZStack to grow, which triggers .onGeometryChange. This changes the size of the photo, which changes the size of the display... which causes continuous looping. For example, this happens when a tall image is shown on a wide screen, such as on an iPad in landscape orientation.
To fix, I would suggest showing the photo in the background of the ZStack. Then add Color.clear to the ZStack, to make sure it fills the full screen. This way, the size of the photo does not impact the size of the ZStack, so it resolves the looping problem:
ZStack {
    Color.clear

    Color.primary.opacity(0.5)
        .mask {
            // ...
        }
}
.background {
    Image(uiImage: selectedPhoto)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: manager.photoSize.width, height: manager.photoSize.height)
        .offset(scaledOffset)
}
// + other modifiers, as before



As always your help is always perfect and kind... Obviously everything works perfectly... oh my god I didn't think I had written such bad code :D :D ... I thought I had done everything correctly and was on the right path...

@kAiN You're welcome, thanks for accepting the answer. I just realised that on point 3, there is no need to add Color.clear to the ZStack, because you already have Color.primary in there. So in fact, you could get rid of the ZStack and apply the image as background to Color.primary (after the mask). Just a small simplification.

in fact I was also thinking about this thing and I was doing it... anyway the color.primary can already be used to give shape to the view and obtain the dimensions we need... Thanks once again you are always very kind. ..thank you so much

if photoAspectRatio > maskAspectRatio {             let width = size.height * photoAspectRatio             return .init(width: width, height: size.height)    } just to clarify I noticed that if instead of having a photo like the one used up to now (which develops in height), we have one that develops in width the division in the calconus doesn't work... Apparently we should multiply by it develops in width and divide if it develops in height.. tell me if this thought of mine is correct.. because otherwise the photo doesn't fit and all the offsets fail

@kAiN Yes, you are absolutely right. I'll correct the answer for completeness.
